# Display total number of days(excluding saturdays and sundays), when two dates are selected using Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-datepicker

I have three `<input>` tags in my code out of which first two accepts date selected using **Bootstrap Datepicker**, and the last one should show the total number of days selected excluding Saturdays and Sundays.

```js
$(function() {

  // create the from date
  $('#from-date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    ConfigureToDate();
  });


  $('#to-date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    startDate: $('#from-date').val()
  });

  // Set the min date on page load
  ConfigureToDate();

  // Resets the min date of the return date
  function ConfigureToDate() {
    $('#to-date').val("").datepicker("update");
    $('#to-date').datepicker('setStartDate', $('#from-date').val());
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input id="from-date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From">
<input id="to-date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To">
<input id="total" class="form-control" placeholder="Total no. of days">
```

I tried some of the other JS solutions that were discussed on this forum. But I'm unable to achieve this functionality.

I have updated my code(including JS) on the following link [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNbUT/711/). It would be great if anyone could solve this for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29933608/136717

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to @photo_tom's comment here is the way. Just get the dates from the inputs and calculate the dates.

Like this:

```js
$(function() {
  // create the from date
  $('#from-date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    ConfigureToDate();
  });


  $('#to-date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    startDate: $('#from-date').val()
  }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    var fromDate = $('#from-date').data('datepicker').dates[0];
    $('#total').val(getBusinessDatesCount(fromDate, ev.date));
  });

  // Set the min date on page load
  ConfigureToDate();

  // Resets the min date of the return date
  function ConfigureToDate() {
    $('#to-date').val("").datepicker("update");
    $('#to-date').datepicker('setStartDate', $('#from-date').val());
  }
});

function getBusinessDatesCount(startDate, endDate) {
  var count = 0;
  var curDate = new Date(startDate);
  while (curDate <= endDate) {
    var dayOfWeek = curDate.getDay();
    if (!((dayOfWeek == 6) || (dayOfWeek == 0)))
      count++;
    curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return count;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input id="from-date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From">
<input id="to-date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To">
<input id="total" class="form-control" placeholder="Total no. of days">
```

Inspired by the question [How to calculate the total days between two selected calendar dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29933608/136717)

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Mosh Feu

Comment: My pleasure   Good luck 

Comment: Hi @Mosh Feu . I now have to add another functionality into the JS such that, an `holiday` in a week( apart from `saturday` and `sunday` ) should also not add to the count.  Eg: When **from-date = 11-04-2018** and **to-date = 16-04-2018** and if **holiday is 12-04-2018**, total days should be **total = 3**. Also when **from** and **to** dates are same, **total days** should be 1.

Comment: Adding few more things to the above comment: I was able to disable all the holiday dates and the weekend days using **datesDisabled** and **daysOfWeekDisabled** option available in the datepicker. Now these disabled dates shouldn't be part of the count. @Mosh Feu . How do I accomplish this? Not able to find a proper workaround.
I have updated my new code here - http://jsfiddle.net/zNbUT/787/

Comment: You can do it the way we did it for weekends. I mean, store an array with all the holidays dates. Then in the `if` check if the day is not holiday, something like: `if (!((dayOfWeek == 6) || (dayOfWeek == 0) || isHoliday(curDate))`.

Comment: I was able to do it! Thanks :)  Updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/qLt6k0yv/

Answer (score 0):

You will have object "days", which contains days (0 - sunday, ..., 6 - saturday) and total value (days.total):

```js
let from = document.getElementById("from-date");
let to = document.getElementById("to-date");
let result = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[2];

let days = {};

from.addEventListener("input",count);
to.addEventListener("input",count);

function count(){
  days = {};

  let fromDate = new Date(from.value);
  let toDate = new Date(to.value);

  if(fromDate == "Invalid Date" || toDate == "Invalid Date") return false;

  for (let i = +fromDate; i <= +toDate; i += 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24){
    let date = new Date(i);
    days[date.getDay()] = days[date.getDay()] + 1 || 1;
  }

  days.total = days[1] + days[2] + days[3] + days[4] + days[5] || 0;
  result.value = days.total;
}
```

```html
<input id="from-date" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="From"> 
<input id="to-date" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="To">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Total no. of days">
```

P.S. it is vanilla JS (may be somebody need pure code without bootstrap and JQuery).